# Copy a column data into next tab with 5 blank cells in b/w each cell data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there any formula to do this or do I need an apps script

A simple A2:A_data in 1st tab needs to be copied to tab 2_A2:A with 5 blank cells in between each data cell!!

**there are no blanks in the to-be-copied A2:A data

Comment: Never mind, got it.. =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(JOIN(" , , , , ,",FILTER(A:A, A:A <> ""))),","))

Comment: You should post a answer with your result and accept it, so the question will not mark as 'unanswered'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your answer from the comment:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(JOIN(" , , , , ,",FILTER(A:A, A:A <> ""))),","))`

---

I like this formula, but I also suggest more general solution:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(JOIN(REPT(", ",5),FILTER(A:A, A:A <> ""))),","))`

- where number `5` in `REPT(", ",5)` is a number of times to repeat blank line

Also there's shorter version:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",FILTER(A:A&REPT(", ",5),A:A<>"")),",",0))`

[image]